# How do I add functions to Zencoding-mode.el to make a - <a> tag - unfold to <a href=" " target=" ">?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emmet

I would like to learn how to add functions to `zencoding-mode.el` ([Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding)). 
Please list what steps a new Emacs user will need to take to enable them to learn [Emacs Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp).

I would love to help extend this Emacs mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather looks to me as if the Zen Coding mode is not what you want to be modifying to do this. From a quick look over the code, it doesn't seem like it has any per-tag rules at all beyond categorising the ones it recognises into either 'single', 'inline', or 'block' tags.

You could clearly write `a.href.target` to get the desired effect, but I don't think the Zen Coding mode is geared to do any automated expansions besides the ones you explicitly specify.

However, it also seems to have some integration with [YASnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet), which most definitely *is* suited to the task. If the Zen Coding mode already does similar things to what you are asking, I would guess that it may actually be YASnippet at work.

As for learning Emacs Lisp, I would redirect you to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522/tips-for-learning-elisp